# How to query UNION over same table and create new columns mysql?

Tags: mysql, union, union-all

I need all X values for selected ids and unite the timestamp if it is equal.
I want to access to this table with php and get the result.

Is this even possible?

i want to 
    SELECT id=1,id=2,id=3,id=5 From data group by timestamp;? there are many ids but i need a query where i can choose the ids and get a result where equal timestamp of multiple x values from different ids is combined.

```
 Table'data'         
+--+-------+--------+---+--+---------+------+
|id|    timestamp   |  Name  | X | Y | other|
+--+-------+--------+---+--+---------+------+
| 1|1.01.14 19:59:21| Müller | 3 | 1 |     1|     
| 2|1.01.14 19:59:21| Schmidt| 5 | 2 |     2|                 
| 3|1.01.16 20:59:22| Taler  | 6 | 3 |     1|       
| 5|1.01.14 19:59:21| Paul   | 10| 2 |     3|
+--+-------+--------+---+--+---------+------+
```

Need Output:

```
 Table'data'         
+----------------+------+------+------+------+-- -+ ---+----+----+
|  timestamp     |  id  |  id  |  id  |  id  |  X | X  | X  | X  |
+----------------+------+------+------+------+-- -+ ---+--- +----+
|1.01.14 19:59:21|   1  |   2  | null |   5  | 3  |  5 |null| 10 |
|1.01.16 20:59:22|  null|  null|   3  |  null|null|null| 6  |null|      
+----------------+------+------+------+------+----+----+----+----+

OR:

Table'data'  Output:   
+----------------+------+------+------+------+
|  timestamp     |  id  |  id  |  id  |  id  |  
+----------------+------+------+------+------+
|1.01.14 19:59:21| 3    |  5   |null  | 10   |
|1.01.16 20:59:22|null  |null  |  6   | null |      
+----------------+------+------+------+------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know the `id` values, you can use `conditional aggregation` to `pivot` your results:

```
select timestamp,
    max(case when id = 1 then id end) id1,
    max(case when id = 2 then id end) id2,
    max(case when id = 3 then id end) id3,
    max(case when id = 5 then id end) id5,
    max(case when id = 1 then x end) x1,
    max(case when id = 2 then x end) x2,
    max(case when id = 3 then x end) x3,
    max(case when id = 5 then x end) x5
from yourtable
group by timestamp
```

I assume for `1.01.16 20:59:22` the value of `6` should be in the 3rd `x`, not the 4th.